# How to write a query, to produce the desired result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use a query, showing the top two best Quantity.  If the table is like the picture, how can the desired result be produced

[image]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()`. For example:

```
select
  id, name, quantity
from (
  select
    id, name, quantity,
    dense_rank() over(order by quantity desc) as rk
  from t
) x
where rk <= 2
```

`DENSE_RANK()` computes a number for each row according to an ordering of your choosing. Identical values get the same number, and no numbers are skipped. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54c97/1).

Comment: Thank you so much,Friend! I got it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TOP/LIMIT functions in query. Which would allow you to select a specific number of rows.

using number as 5 you can get the desired result from:

SELECT *columnname* FROM *tablename* WHERE condition LIMIT *number*;

or

SELECT TOP  (number)/(percent) *columnname* FROM *tablename* WHERE *condition*;